# Being a friend to someone vs Being a friend of someone

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between these two sentences?

> He is a close friend of my sister.
> He is a close friend to my sister.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that a person is a friend "of" someone, you're describing a relationship between the two.

When you say that a person is a friend "to" someone (or even something), you're describing that person's actions and qualities as well as the helpfulness, importance, or significance that flows from those qualities or actions.

So, to say that "Person A is a close friend of Person B," is to say that A and B know one another and that B regards A as a close friend.

To say that "Person A is a friend to Person B" would describe A as someone who has been of help to or been supportive of B in an important way. It does not imply a close friendship, and in fact, it isn't even necessesary for them to know one another personally at all. For instance, I could say that "Mother Theresa was a friend to all those in need." That means that her life's work was important and beneficial to all those in need. It does not imply that she knew them all personally.

I would suggest that to use the word "close" in the "to" context is mistaken, because - unless it has some meaning that I can't see - it throws the light back onto the relationship between the two parties.

Comment: You wouldn't typically say "A is a friend to B".  With "to" you would use a past tense (_was_, _has been_) to mark specific actions the friend undertook.  With present tense, you'd be commenting on B's perception of A as a friend (whether or not it was true on A's part).

Comment: +1 particularly for the final point (an observation I made myself in a comment to the actual question, before scrolling to the bottom of your answer to see you'd already made exactly the same point).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You might say *a **true** friend to B*, however.

Comment: Yes, a ***true*** friend can be the same as a ***good*** friend - where as Jeff points out above, it's possible to use these terms even if the two people don't know one another personally at all. But you can't normally be a ***close*** friend of someone you've never met, no matter how many things you do to their benefit.